# Get smart-select struct's value inside Gorm's AfterFind() hook

Tags: go, hook, go-gorm

I have this model:

```
 type User struct {
      ID     uint
      Name   string
      Age    int
      Gender string
      // hundreds of fields
 }
```

with this hook:

```
func (m *User) AfterFind(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  // I don't know how to get Gender value of APIUser struct from here
  return
}
```

And this smart select struct:

```
type APIUser struct {
  ID   uint
  Gender string
}
```

then I run this query:

```
DB.Model(&User{}).Find(&APIUser{}, id)
```

Inside AfterFind() hook I want to manipulate retrieved data from database before send them to client, but I couldn't get the value inside this hook. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`AfterFind`](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Querying-an-object) should be set to both `APIUser` and `User`

Here are sample codes

```golang
type User struct {
    Id       uint64
    Avatar   string
    Nickname string
    Password string
}

func (user *User) AfterFind(*gorm.DB) error {
    return nil
}

type UserSimple struct {
    Id     uint64
    Avatar string
}

func (v *UserSimple) AfterFind(*gorm.DB) error {
    v.Avatar = "prefix/" + v.Avatar
    return nil
}

us := &UserSimple{}
db.Model(&User{}).Where("id = ?", 123).Find(us)
```

Output

```
{123 prefix/avatar}
```